# Yii app updateCounters (page views) best way?

Tags: php, yii

I have a Yii Powered web app with a controller (PostController) and a "view" column in database.

How can I update these rows when visitors view Post page?

Now my code is working, but is it correct or are there any comments/suggestions?

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
    Quotes::model()->updateCounters(array('views'=>+1), 'id=' . $id );
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the number of views is the only thing you want to track? not the date or unique visitor? if so, you would want a separate table for views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the Quotes model:

```
public function afterFind() {
    $this->view++;
    $this->save();
}
```

this will update views everytime after find.
in controller:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),//or 'model'=>Quotes::model()->findByPk($id)
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.1.8, you can use such code:

```
$this->saveCounters(array('views'=>1));
```

It would be faster. See more information here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveCounters-detail

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Model for your Post. If you name that model for example Post (if you don't already have that). You need to update the value using this PHP code:

```
Post::model()->updateByPk(1, array('view' => 2));
```

Assuming your row has an ID with value 1 (Page ID for example) and you want to update the view column with the value 2.

The type of your model is CActiveRecord. Find great documentation at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateByPk-detail

Comment: where can me write this code ? module or controller ? and where ?